# How to run Selenium Test across a set of machines using Run Functional Test build step in TFS build setup

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, tfsbuild, build-agent

I have close to 7000 test cases (using MSTest Framework) and have categorized into say 
category A, B, C, D, E,F,G . Each of the category has 1000 test cases.

I have 7 VMs and planning to deploy and run the test in all seven machines. I am quite clear till Step 4 ( please see image below )

[image]

But I am not sure how to configure Step 5 which is Run Functional Test.

I am able to triggerall the 7000 test in one machine. But and all is good..

But I am not able to find a provision to run test in a distributed fashion based in the test category.

Say, I want to run all

Test which falls under Test Category A in VM1

Test which falls under Test Category B in VM2

Test which falls under Test Category C in VM3

Test which falls under Test Category D in VM4

Test which falls under Test Category E in VM5

Test which falls under Test Category F in VM6

Test which falls under Test Category G in VM7

[image]

Can any one please point to me the missing link here and what I need to do to make it working in the above said fashion. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your project to generate the test assemblies base on category (one category one test assembly) since the parallelism for Run Functional Test task is at the test assembly level.

> Given multiple machines in the Test Machine Group, the task can do
>   parallel distributed execution of your tests. Parallelism is at the
>   test assembly level.

Check this link for details: [Visual Studio Test using Test Agent Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests).